# Mongodb not using index intersection when using $all over a multikey index

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create a collection where each object can have varying number of properties and I have to filter objects on multiple property and return the results sorted on the field sortoder. So, I added these properties as an array and created  multikey index on my collection

`db.ixisect.createIndex({"dimensions": 1, "sortorder": -1});`

This is how my data looks

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong("79076429340352512"),
    "record" : {
        "fiid" : NumberLong("79076429340352512"),
        "actor" : "Salmonweak",
        "action" : "Gematom",
        "data" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed molestie, lectus eu suscipit vulputate, orci magna gravida nibh, quis dignissim risus ipsum sed urna. Maecenas ullamcorper ligula a ipsum venenatis, ac sodales massa tincidunt. Ut odio diam, commodo in viverra vitae, eleifend sit amet eros. Aenean at enim ac tortor faucibus imperdiet non ac mauris. Ut pulvinar, eros et auctor suscipit, nunc lorem varius odio, vel ullamcorper ante urna at lorem. Duis volutpat egestas augue nec hendrerit. In venenatis vestibulum elit ut commodo. Donec ac elementum lectus, quis ultricies lacus. Duis placerat nec sapien luctus pharetra. Nulla facilisi.Nullam condimentum efficitur leo at condimentum. Pellentesque rhoncus massa arcu, eget tincidunt odio congue non. Etiam in ultricies lacus. Pellentesque pulvinar, turpis nec fringilla placerat, libero erat scelerisque tellus, nec pellentesque ligula tellus sit amet urna. Mauris lacinia cursus mauris, sed sollicitudin risus interdum in"
    },
    "dimensions" : [
        "500001110",
        "50000124",
        "50000133",
        "50000148",
        "50000157"
    ],
    "sortorder" : NumberLong("79076429340352512")
}
```

`db.ixisect.find( {dimensions: {$all: ["90000119", "90000144"]}}).explain(true)`

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "feeds.ixisect",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [
            {
                "dimensions" : {
                    "$eq" : "90000119"
                }
            },
            {
                "dimensions" : {
                    "$eq" : "90000144"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "dimensions" : {
                "$eq" : "90000119"
            }
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "dimensions" : 1,
                "sortorder" : -1
            },
            "indexName" : "dimensions_1_sortorder_-1",
            "isMultiKey" : true,
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 1,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "dimensions" : [
                    "[\"90000144\", \"90000144\"]"
                ],
                "sortorder" : [
                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [
        {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "dimensions" : {
                    "$eq" : "90000144"
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "dimensions" : 1,
                    "sortorder" : -1
                },
                "indexName" : "dimensions_1_sortorder_-1",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "dimensions" : [
                        "[\"90000119\", \"90000119\"]"
                    ],
                    "sortorder" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 13,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 1,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 106,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 106,
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "dimensions" : {
                "$eq" : "90000119"
            }
        },
        "nReturned" : 13,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
        "works" : 108,
        "advanced" : 13,
        "needTime" : 93,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 1,
        "restoreState" : 1,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "docsExamined" : 106,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned" : 106,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 107,
            "advanced" : 106,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 1,
            "restoreState" : 1,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "keyPattern" : {
                "dimensions" : 1,
                "sortorder" : -1
            },
            "indexName" : "dimensions_1_sortorder_-1",
            "isMultiKey" : true,
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 1,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "dimensions" : [
                    "[\"90000144\", \"90000144\"]"
                ],
                "sortorder" : [
                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                ]
            },
            "keysExamined" : 106,
            "dupsTested" : 106,
            "dupsDropped" : 0,
            "seenInvalidated" : 0
        }
    },
    "allPlansExecution" : [
        {
            "nReturned" : 12,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "totalKeysExamined" : 107,
            "totalDocsExamined" : 107,
            "executionStages" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "dimensions" : {
                        "$eq" : "90000144"
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 12,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 107,
                "advanced" : 12,
                "needTime" : 95,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 1,
                "restoreState" : 1,
                "isEOF" : 0,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 107,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 107,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 107,
                    "advanced" : 107,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 1,
                    "restoreState" : 1,
                    "isEOF" : 0,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "dimensions" : 1,
                        "sortorder" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "dimensions_1_sortorder_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "dimensions" : [
                            "[\"90000119\", \"90000119\"]"
                        ],
                        "sortorder" : [
                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 107,
                    "dupsTested" : 107,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "nReturned" : 13,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "totalKeysExamined" : 106,
            "totalDocsExamined" : 106,
            "executionStages" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "dimensions" : {
                        "$eq" : "90000119"
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 13,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 107,
                "advanced" : 13,
                "needTime" : 93,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 1,
                "restoreState" : 1,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 106,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 106,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 107,
                    "advanced" : 106,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 1,
                    "restoreState" : 1,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "dimensions" : 1,
                        "sortorder" : -1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "dimensions_1_sortorder_-1",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "dimensions" : [
                            "[\"90000144\", \"90000144\"]"
                        ],
                        "sortorder" : [
                            "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 106,
                    "dupsTested" : 106,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "ShreyasMBP.local",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.2.9",
    "gitVersion" : "22ec9e93b40c85fc7cae7d56e7d6a02fd811088c"
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

Mongo does not even consider the index intersection plan here.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071 says It will consider self index intersection on a multikey index. Am I missing something here?

I'm using mongodb version 3.2